# localStack started in docker on Windows 10, but unable to connect via localhost

Tags: windows, docker, localhost, localstack

I am starting localstack in docker with this command

```
docker run -it --name localstack  localstack/localstack:latest -p 4567-4584:4567-4584
```

It appears to start up correctly

```
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
2020-06-26 20:32:46,508 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
2020-06-26 20:32:46,510 INFO supervisord started with pid 13
2020-06-26 20:32:47,513 INFO spawned: 'dashboard' with pid 19
2020-06-26 20:32:47,514 INFO spawned: 'infra' with pid 20
2020-06-26 20:32:47,520 INFO success: dashboard entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
(. .venv/bin/activate; bin/localstack web)
LocalStack version: 0.11.2
(. .venv/bin/activate; exec bin/localstack start --host)
LocalStack version: 0.11.2
Starting local dev environment. CTRL-C to quit.
!WARNING! - Looks like you have configured $LAMBDA_REMOTE_DOCKER=1 - please make sure to configure $HOST_TMP_FOLDER to point to your host's $TMPDIR
2020-06-26 20:32:49,263 INFO success: infra entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-06-26T20:32:51:INFO:localstack.utils.common: Error storing key/cert SSL files (falling back to random tmp file names): [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/localstack/server.test.pem.key'
Running on 0.0.0.0:8081 over https (CTRL + C to quit)
Starting edge router (https port 4566)...
Starting mock API Gateway service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4567 (deprecated)...
Running on 0.0.0.0:4566 over https (CTRL + C to quit)
2020-06-26T20:32:51:INFO:localstack.multiserver: Starting multi API server process on port 46661
Running on 0.0.0.0:4567 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
Running on 0.0.0.0:46661 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
Starting mock CloudFormation service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4581 (deprecated)...
Starting mock CloudWatch service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4582 (deprecated)...
Starting mock DynamoDB service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4569 (deprecated)...
Starting mock DynamoDB Streams service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4570 (deprecated)...
Starting mock EC2 service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4597 (deprecated)...
Starting mock ES service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4578 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Firehose service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4573 (deprecated)...
Starting mock IAM service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4593 (deprecated)...
Starting mock STS service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4592 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Kinesis service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4568 (deprecated)...
Starting mock KMS service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4599 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Lambda service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4574 (deprecated)...
Starting mock CloudWatch Logs service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4586 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Redshift service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4577 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Route53 service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4580 (deprecated)...
Starting mock S3 service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4572 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Secrets Manager service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4584 (deprecated)...
Starting mock SES service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4579 (deprecated)...
Running on 0.0.0.0:4581 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
Running on 0.0.0.0:4569 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
Running on 0.0.0.0:4593 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
Running on 0.0.0.0:4568 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
Running on 0.0.0.0:4599 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
Running on 0.0.0.0:4586 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
Running on 0.0.0.0:4572 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
Running on 0.0.0.0:4584 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
Starting mock SNS service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4575 (deprecated)...
Starting mock SQS service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4576 (deprecated)...
Starting mock SSM service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4583 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Cloudwatch Events service on http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4587 (deprecated)...
Starting mock StepFunctions service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4585 (deprecated)...
Running on 0.0.0.0:4575 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
Running on 0.0.0.0:4576 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
Running on 0.0.0.0:4583 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
Running on 0.0.0.0:4587 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
Running on 0.0.0.0:4585 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
Ready.
```

but I am unable to get a response in the browser via

```
localhost:4567 or 127.0.0.1:4567 or any of the other ports.
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing incorrectly? Windows firewall is turned off.
I am not using docker-compose, but that just does what the command line does I believe.

Netstats for ports shows

```
 TCP    127.0.0.1:4573         Da-Beast:0             LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:4573         kubernetes:59207       CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:4573         kubernetes:61610       CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27060        Da-Beast:0             LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49698        kubernetes:49699       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49699        kubernetes:49698       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53768        Da-Beast:0             LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54061        Da-Beast:0             LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:59207        kubernetes:4573        FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61610        kubernetes:4573        FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    127.0.0.1:64961        kubernetes:5037        SYN_SENT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:64962        kubernetes:5037        SYN_SENT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:64963        kubernetes:5037        SYN_SENT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:64964        kubernetes:5037        SYN_SENT
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: I did not figure out how to resolve it.

Comment: Ok, I too faced the same issue but as I was testing to work with only S3 , I manage to run it by "docker run -p 4572:4572 -e SERVICES=s3 localstack/localstack", we can add the services list as comma separated so may be you can try if it helps